# ASP.NET Core DataProtection master key from environment variables

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, environment-variables, load-balancing

I am trying to set up the Data Protection on a distributed environment so that the same keys would be used in multiple instances. I want the users to be able to decrypt the cookies despite the server instance they are hitting. External key storage like Redis/Azure Storage or storing data protection keys to a database is not an option in our case.

Is there a simple way to set the master key from the environment variables? In our case, we want to be able to specify the keys using Kubernetes.